# Are there such things as dynamic-dimensional arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, multidimensional-array

What I mean by dynamic-dimensional arrays is multidimensional arrays that can have various dimensions. I need to create a function that does something to elements of multidimensional arrays, regardless of their dimensions. I wrote a function that should loop through all elements of a multidimensional array, but I can't find a way to get them. Here's what I wrote:

```
function loopThrough (multiArray, dimensions) {

  var i, indexes = new Array(dimensions.length);
  // stores the current position in multiArray as index combination

  for (i in indexes) indexes[i] = 0; // position is initialised with [0, 0, ... 0]

  while (i >= 0) {

    doStuff(multiArray[indexes[0], indexes[1], ... indexes[?]]); // this is where I got stuck

    for (i = indexes.length - 1; i >= 0 && ++indexes[i] >= dimensions[i]; indexes[i--] = 0);
    // creates the next index combination

  }

}
```

I also need a way to create such arrays. Say in an object's constructor, like:

```
function MultiArray (dimensions) {

  this.array = [];

  // create multidimensional array

}
```

For example, if I want to create a 5x3x8 array I should be able to call `MultiArray([5,3,8]);` just the same as calling `MultiArray([4,6]);` for a 4x6 array, or `MultiArray([7]);` for a plain 7-lengthed array.

Comment: An example of dimentions?

Comment: You have to use recursion

Comment: @hindmost you don't _have to_, but that is _one way_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function MultiArray(dimensions) {
    this.elements = [];
    var leaf = dimensions.length == 1;
    var dimension = dimensions.shift();
    for (var i = 0; i < dimension; ++i) {
        this.elements.push(leaf ? undefined : new MultiArray(dimensions));
    }
}

MultiArray.prototype.get(indexes) {
    var leaf = indexes.length == 1;
    var index = indexes.shift();
    return leaf ? this.elements[index] : this.elements[index].get(indexes);
}

MultiArray.prototype.set(indexes, value) {
    var leaf = indexes.length == 1;
    var index = indexes.shift();
    if (leaf) {
        this.elements[index] = value;
    } else {
        this.elements[index].set(indexes, value);
    }
    return this;
}

var m = new MultiArray([4, 3, 5]);
m.set([1, 2, 4], "i'm a value in a multi dimensional array");
m.get([1, 2, 4]); // should return "i'm a value in a multi dimensional array"
m.get([2, 0, 3]); // should return undefined
m.get([0, 1]); // should return an array of 5 elements
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
function MultiArray(dimensions) {
    var a = [];
    if (dimensions > 1) {
        a.push(MultiArray(dimensions -1));
    }
    return a;
}
var m = MultiArray(4);
```

Comment: +1, though the name might better be lowercased as it is a factory function, not a constructor.